# How do I remove a line break (\n) in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table of addresses that have certain addresses listed as 123 Clock St \nAPTB.

How do I remove the "\n" and have there be a space between the street address and apt number.

I tried using the Replace function, but it didn't seem to work. Am I formatting it correctly?

Here is what I was using:

```
Select * from address_table;
UPDATE address_table SET address = replace (address, '\n', '');
```

Comment: try with double  Quotes instead of single "\n"

Comment: If you want to replace "\n" by a space, you should put a space (' ') in your replace call instead of an empty string ('').

Comment: Do you want to replace a single newline character (`\n`) or its escaped representation, that is a sequence of the backslash and newline chars? i.e. it really depends on what you actually means got within `123 Clock St \nAPTB`

Comment: Thanks everyone for all of your help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As backslash ('\') is an escape character, you should double it :

```
Select * from address_table;
UPDATE address_table SET address = replace (address, '\\n', ' ');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. This worked =)

Comment: ok, so the need was to replace the sequence of the backslash and newline chars :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably the correct masking of you newline character. I have not yet found a solution for that but the following worked for me in Sql-server and MySql:

```
select replace(address,'
',' ');
```

In SQL it is permissible to have *actual* linefeeds in a string literal.

(I tried the otherwise suggested doubling of escape characters first, but for me it did not work it.
Edit: The escape character solution *does* work too: http://rextester.com/IZCF14460 , but *without* doubling them.)